# processAjaxOnInit: is set to "false" but Ajax is still called

Tags: tablesorter

I'm preloading my table using PHP and then have processAjaxOnInit: false in my config. What happens is that the call to my Ajax url is still made and instead of appending rows to the table it wipes out the rows that are there. I'm assuming that it's still making the call to get the total number of rows. Can I set this on page load and completely bypass calling the Ajax url?

Thanks

```js
.tablesorterPager({

  container: $(".pager"),

  ajaxUrl : '/documents_table_data.php?page={page}&size={size}&{filterList:filter}&{sortList:column}',

  // use this option to manipulate and/or add additional parameters to the ajax url
  customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
    // manipulate the url string as you desire
    //url += '&archive=<?php echo $_GET[archive] ?>&wor=<?php echo $_GET[wor] ?>';

    // trigger a custom event; if you want
    $(table).trigger('changingUrl', url);
    // send the server the current page
    return url;
  },
  ajaxError: null,
  ajaxObject: {
    dataType: 'json'
  },
  ajaxProcessing: function(data){
    if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
      var r, row, c, d = data.rows,
      total = data.total_rows,
      headers = data.headers,
      rows = [],
      len = d.length;
      for ( r=0; r < len; r++ ) {
        row = [];
        for ( c in d[r] ) {
          if (typeof(c) === "string") {
            row.push(d[r][c]);
          }
        }
        // is there a way to do that here when it pushes the row onto the array
        // or perhaps there is another funtion you have implemented that will let me do that
        rows.push(row);
      }
      return [ total, rows, headers ];
    }
  },

  // Set this option to false if your table data is preloaded into the table, but you are still using ajax
  processAjaxOnInit: false,
  output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',
  updateArrows: true,
  page: 0,
  size: 10,
  savePages: true,
  storageKey: 'tablesorter-pager',
  pageReset: 0,
  fixedHeight: false,
  removeRows: false,
  countChildRows: false,

  // css class names of pager arrows
  cssNext        : '.next',  // next page arrow
  cssPrev        : '.prev',  // previous page arrow
  cssFirst       : '.first', // go to first page arrow
  cssLast        : '.last',  // go to last page arrow
  cssGoto        : '.gotoPage', // page select dropdown - select dropdown that set the "page" option

  cssPageDisplay : '.pagedisplay', // location of where the "output" is displayed
  cssPageSize    : '.pagesize', // page size selector - select dropdown that sets the "size" option

  // class added to arrows when at the extremes; see the "updateArrows" option
  // (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
  cssDisabled    : 'disabled', // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
  cssErrorRow    : 'tablesorter-errorRow' // error information row

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added a pager option named `initialRows` (currently only available in the master branch). When `processAjaxOnInit` is `false` and this option is set, no initial ajax call to the server is done ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/uwZc2/55/)):

```js
$(function(){
  $('table').tablesorter({
    widgets: ['pager'],
    widgetOptions : {
      pager_processAjaxOnInit: false,
      pager_initialRows: {
        // these are both set to 50 initially
        // the server can return different values
        // and the output will update automatically
        total: 50,
        filtered: 50
      },
      // other ajax settings...
    }
  });
});
```